# Separating columns in GridView for CSV files

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to get help on how to separate the columns for displaying contents of the csv files that I have uploaded.

```
//  get all lines of csv file
     string[] str = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/MyPlace"));

    // get the column header means first line
    string[] temp = str[0].Split(',');
    // creates columns of gridview as per the header name

     // now retrieve the record from second line and add it to datatable
    for(int i=1;i<str.Length;i++)
    {
        string[] t = str[i].Split(',');


    }
    // assign gridview datasource property by datatable
    myGridView.DataSource = str;
    // bind the gridview
    myGridView.DataBind();
```

As you can see, I've already done the splitting with the Split(',') command, but when I debug it, it will display all the contents in one column, and not in different rows and columns. How to separate the contents into different columns and rows?

Comment: I don't think using `String.Split` to parse CSV files is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

yes you did the split but you stored the result in the local variable t inside your loop and never used it.
You might try

```
var data =
   File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/MyPlace"))
   .Select(line => line.Split(','))
   .Select(columns => new {FirstColumnName = columns[0], SecondColumnName = columns[1] /*, ... */});
myGridView.DataSource = data;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

This snippet should just read your file line by line, first splitting the lines into arrays (columns) and then creating an annonymous class object for each line containing FirstColumName = first item in line, etc.

Example:

```
    var test = "Donald,Duck\nMickey,Mouse";

    var data =
       test.Split('\n')
       .Select(line => line.Split(','))
       .Select(columns => new { FirstColumnName = columns[0], SecondColumnName = columns[1] /*, ... */});

    GridView1.DataSource = data;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

having only the simplest page (just a GridView dragged onto the page) yields the following:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast answer! I did try what you suggested, but there was an error at the myGridview.DataBind(); part, the error was, "The data source for GridView with id 'myGridView' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content." What does that means?

Comment: Thanks a lot @CKoenig, sorry to trouble you, cos I'm new at this =/

Comment: there was a ')' missing in Line 3 but aside from that my quick test asp.net page with the test data I add above is running

Comment: oh wait - I guess the problem is the C#2.0 - in this case not even LINQ is avaiable and you shouldn't be able to compile this code at all - is this right?